# nativescript marshalling error

Tags: ios, objective-c, marshalling, nativescript

I seem to be getting a strange problem when marshaling the following native iOS code to nativescript:

```
CGRect keyboardRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 216);
AGEmojiKeyboardView *emojiKeyboardView = [[AGEmojiKeyboardView alloc] initWithFrame:keyboardRect
                                                                           dataSource:self];
emojiKeyboardView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
emojiKeyboardView.delegate = self;
self.textView.inputView = emojiKeyboardView;
```

The equivalent I came up with is the following:

```
var keyboardRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, platform.screen.mainScreen.widthPixels, 216);
var emojiKeyboardView = new AGEmojiKeyboardView();
emojiKeyboardView.frame = keyboardRect;
emojiKeyboardView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
emojiKeyboardView.delegate = this;
views.textInput.ios.inputView = emojiKeyboardView;
```

where platform is just `require("platform");` and `views.textInput` is a view to which I need to set the inputView to AGEmojiKeyboardView.

I really don't understand where I went wrong. All that appears is a grey keyboard with no content.

EDIT:

I changed the js code to the following:

```
var keyboardRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, uiView.view.frame.size.width, 216);
var emojiKeyboardView = new AGEmojiKeyboardView(keyboardRect, uiView);
emojiKeyboardView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
emojiKeyboardView.delegate = uiView;
views.textInput.ios.inputView = emojiKeyboardView;
```

where uiView is just page.ios and something seems to happen now, but still not the intended result. An exception is thrown, namely the following: `-[UIViewControllerImpl emojiKeyboardView:imageForSelectedCategory:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7e6bff60`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As NativeScript has TypeScript as first-class member somethings are really easier to do with TS. For example you can also use the [META-Generator](http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/how-to/Use-Native-Libraries#troubleshooting)
Simply run this two lines to generate metadata & typings for your CocoaPod (and all other Objective-C files) and you won't have to worry about the right syntax.(still you will need to know the basic rules)

```
TNS_DEBUG_METADATA_PATH="$(pwd)/metadata" tns build ios [--for-device] [--release]

TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH="$(pwd)/typings" tns build ios [--for-device] [--release]
```

Also if you want to createa a custom view the best variant is using NativeScript ***placeholder*** with ***creatingView***

As for the syntax it shouldb look similar to this but still you will have to create your own ViewController and as the author says - conform to ***AGEmojiKeyboardViewDataSource*** and ***AGEmojiKeyboardViewDelegate*** protocol.

```
var frame = require('ui/frame');
var page;

function onLoaded(args) {
     page = args.object;

}
exports.onLoaded = onLoaded;

function onCreatingView(args) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var uiView = page.ios.view; // replace with own UIView and conform to AGEmojiKeyboardViewDataSource and AGEmojiKeyboardViewDelegate protocol.

        var frame = {origin: {x:0, y:0}, size: {width: uiView.frame.size.width, height:600}};
        var emojiView = AGEmojiKeyboardView.alloc().initWithFrameDataSource(frame, uiView);
        emojiView.autoresizingMask = UIView.UIViewAutoresizing.UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        emojiView.delegate = uiView;

        var textContainer = NSTextContainer.alloc().initWithSize({width: 80, height: 180});

        var frame = {origin: {x:0, y:0}, size: {width: 100, height:220}};
        var textView = UITextView.alloc().initWithFrameTextContainer(frame, textContainer);
        textView.inputView = emojiView;

        args.view = textView;
    }, 500);
}
exports.onCreatingView = onCreatingView;
```

page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="onLoaded">
  <StackLayout>
        <Placeholder creatingView="onCreatingView" id="placeholder-view"/>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: I didn't know that I could generate the typescript typings for the the Cocoapods. This is really interesting thanks for that tip! I'll test your solution and I hope that it works!

Comment: your suggestion to alter the TNS_METADATA_PATH and TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH produces a duplicate identifier for everything in the typings folder

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but I don't think you are using marshalling properly.

The documentation states:

```
AGEmojiKeyboardView *emojiKeyboardView = [[AGEmojiKeyboardView alloc] initWithFrame:keyboardRect dataSource:self];
```

So your {N} version should be something like this:

```
var emojiKeyboardView = AGEmojiKeyboardView.alloc().initWithFrameDataSource(keyboardRect, uiView);
```

This is a great blog-post on how to create plugins based on 3rd party libraries for nativescript. It also explains step-by-step how this type of marshalling is done. 
http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=167

Comment: Hi, 
thank you for your response. I'll try it and let you know